# Setting a revealing onhover behaviour for multiple elements-pairs with only CSS - how come this works?

Tags: css, css-selectors

*Maybe it's a strange question since I don't wanna know 'how' but 'why', but I think the answer might be valuable for those who wish to understand the way css works better.*

I'm trying to make each div on my page reveal an 'x' div which will allow the user to close that div. There are several dynamically created divs.

I have this (dynamic) html:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="x">X</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="x">X</div>
</div>
```

[the number of 'box' divs varies]

And this css:

```
.x {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.box:hover .x {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

I really didn't think this could work but somehow it does:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aPuw/)

**But how does this simple css code 'knows' which x div should be revealed, where there are no ids to distinct the 'box' divs nor the 'x' divs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it looks for the **descendent** `.x`
So when you hover over box 2 it applies the `:hover` and according to the css rule the `.x` that's inside the `.box` with the `:hover` should be visible.

Wouldn't really know how to explain it differently :P